# Rest Assured, logging outbound traffic doesn't log well

Tags: json, rest, junit, jackson, rest-assured

I am logging all inbound and outbound rest assured junit traffic, using:

```
RequestSpecification re = given().when();
re.log().all();
```

This works well for inbound and outbound except for post requests. When i send a post request, it prints payload with ascii characters:

```
Request method: POST
Request URI:    http://localhost:2080/prog/v1.0/customer/acme/16/all/   Proxy:                  <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Multiparts:             <none>
Headers:                X-Sender-ApplicationId=DWEB
                                X-Sender-UserId=foobar
                                Authorization=Basic ZHdlYjspkd22VidsIzExMQ==
                                Accept=*/*
                                Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8
Cookies:                <none>
Body:
[123, 34, 115, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 34, 58, 34, 70, 114, 101, 101, 34, 44, 34, 115, 116, 97, 116, 117, 115, 68, 97, 116, 101, 34, 58, 123, 34, 99, 101, 110, 116, 117,......]
```

It doesn't log payload body of post request properly. Is there any setting  i need to do for it print in readable format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it. Issue I was adding POST body as bytes (as following)

```
    re.body(json.getBytes());
```

Changed it to

```
    re.body(json);
```

Payload is now showing up nicely as plain text :-). Should've known better.